# In python, how do I make it so that I can have two programs read from a serial port?

Tags: python, serial-port, monitoring

I have a python program that processes serial data as it comes in and sends data back out. I now need a separate python program that only monitors needs to use the same serial port as the other program, and it will not respond only monitor.

Any idea how I can do this? Unless I am missing something, I am not sure how to make it so there are two listeners to the same serial port.

Comment: Usually two programs cannot bind to the same port... if you give more specifics about the program maybe I can help you more. You may want to try writing one program to listen to the port and do both, or call the other two programs with new data.

Comment: First python program just receives the serial data to send it via TCP to another application on another server.

The second python program is just to monitor what goes in and out of the serial port for monitoring and debugging.

Comment: Simply read data from serial port in one of the programs and write it into a Sqlite database, in other program use database data